# Why are unions good for low level system programming in C?

Tags: c, unions

In one of the textbooks on C, I have read that unions are very useful when it comes to low level system programming. I would like to know why is it so?

Why would unions be a good choice for low level system programming?

Comment: AFAIK unions and structs serve different purposes, so you're comparing apples to oranges... unless you describe what the author meant with "better". Better for what purpose? Better by which meter?

Comment: This assertion is so broad that no sane person would call it true. And "very useful" means something totally different than "better".

Comment: Why its not a real question??

Comment: Ok let me correct the question.

Comment: This is really a matter of opinion.  I think that a `union` is an awful construct that encourages side-stepping all forms of type-safety.  That isn't to say that it doesn't have a place, but, IMO, there is usually a better way to get what you want.

Comment: Which textbook are you reading this in?

Comment: @Travis Gockel: low level system programming == side-stepping all forms of type-safety

Comment: Used carefully, a `union` can be type-safe.  Used carelessly, most of C can be used to make a real mess, and unions are no different from the rest of C.

Comment: @duedl0r: I disagree. Compile-time type checking has no runtime cost. While there are situations where one *has* to turn off the safety, that certainly shouldn't be the norm.  I agree with Jonathan, although I would argue that a `union` is one of the most error-prone constructs. Again, matter of opinion.

Comment: Textbook is "C in depth" written by indian authors.

Comment: Link to book or it didn't happen.

Comment: http://www.infibeam.com/Books/info/srivastava/c-depth-2nd-revised-edition/8183330487.html

Answer (score 4):

Well, your text book should explain what it means -- we can only second guess the intention.

However one use i have seen in os-drivers and the like is the mapping of hardware registers for the device to multiple views.  So if a IO device have a io-address represented by a word, you may want to address the entire word or the high order byte etc.

While you can do that with pointers and casting them, then a clearner way is to have a union of

```
  union {
      unsigned short word;
      struct {
           unsigned char high;
           unsigned char low;
      } byte;
   };
```

which now allows addressing the entire `word` or part of it by `byte.high` etc.

However union is not a replacement or alternative for struct -- they serve different purposes -- and one such purpose *could* be to have different view of the same memory.

Comment: +1 for an example of a mix of structures and unions, showing that both are equally useful.

Comment: @mouviciel: Though it's rare to ever see a `union` that didn't use a `struct` as one of the member types (directly or indirectly).

Answer (score 2):

`union`s allow you to have different types but only one of them can actually be used at any time.  So if you are in a constrained environment for example, then this could be useful.

A `struct` on the other hand, will reserve memory for all it's types inside it, which means you are using more memory, though you can now use all the variables in the `struct`

That one is necessarily better then the other, I don't know that this is a correct statement.  They serve two different purposes.

Comment: I'm hoping he's not intending to just replace `union` with `struct` in his definitions.  I read the question as being using an individual `struct` type versus a `union` of types.

Comment: @Jeff I hope too that this is not what the OP is going to do, else he will have a problem

Comment: IMO union is not here for saving memory. You don't save a thing.. it's like saying a pointer to a memory location saves memory, because you can save different things at one memory location.

Comment: i did ask a very specific thing!!

Answer (score 1):

Unions and structures are two different constructs. It is nonsense to say that one is better than the other.

Are pineapples better than philosophy for swimming?

Comment: If pineapples float they're obviously better...

Comment: Fine @mouviciel but why unions alone are good for low level system programming .leave this comparison aside.

Comment: Low level system programming need a mix of unions and structures. Have a look at a TCP/IP stack for an example.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated: `union` and `struct` don't serve the same purpose.

Unions are useful if you want to do byte operations, for example:

```
union {
   int i;
   char pi[4];
}
```

You can easily access some bytes of the variable `i` without doing difficult casts, which is very common in low level programming.

Comment: And structures are useful if you want to do bit operations. Both are useful for low level system programming.

Answer (score 0):

Unions & structure both are used in different situation for different purpose.! you can never use union in place of structure & vice versa 
for better understaning be clear with structure & union's spec

Answer (score 0):

You are likely to encounter 10-100 `struct`s for every `union` that you encounter.

The two (`struct`s and `union`s) are related, but they do different jobs.  A union may be used to save space when you need to store different values in a single unit of space at different times.  A structure is more generally useful; it collects together a number of values that need to be stored and accessed together (and which cannot share space).

Yes, `union` can be useful in low-level programming.  So, too, can `struct`.  Neither is better than the other because they do different jobs.  You can't use a `union` when you need a `struct`.  You can survive without using `union`, but when they're useful, `union`s are very useful.

Given a choice between being able to use only one or the other, I'd choose to be able to use `struct` every time.

Comment: "C in depth" and they have mentioned like unions are useful when it comes to low level programming.There they have given the example how do you find machine byte order using union."

Comment: There they are straining to find a use for unions; that is not an important use of unions, in general.

Answer (score 0):

This is false - you can't change structure for unions. The difference is in memory usage. In structure all variables take separated places in memory. So the size of structure is sum of it's variables (often + padding).

On the other side unions are as big as their biggest variable, all variables are residing in 1 place in memory, so modifying one variable changes contents of other variables in union.